# suPHP usergroup reset to default at midnight in httpd.conf, how to avoid this?

Tags: httpd.conf

I have 3 domains that need to point to the same public_html folder. So I've setup a http.conf for those domains.

Let's say that I have user/group :

```
master
slave1
slave2
slave3
```

All slaves should point to master. So I've made in sort that the suPHP usergroup is

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup master master
</IfModule>
```

for all slaves

But it seems that at midnight, when cPanel updates... they revert back to

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup slave1 slave1
    </IfModule>
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup slave2 slave2
    </IfModule>
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup slave3 slave3
    </IfModule>
```

How to avoid this checkup on cPanel or is there a way to override this file so it can read another one that it won't rewrite/reset ?